# SQL Join query that selects rows and checks if they exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sequelpro

Not sure if this is possible in a single query but looking to do this directly in SequelPro.

I have a table containing cars, and if they are sold or live.

I also have another table which is called data_store and contains some information about those cars. However, not all of the cars have data in this table.

To get the cars that are live is currently:

```
SELECT * from cars where `sale_status` = 'live'
```

I now need it to be like:

```
SELECT * from cars where `sale_status` = 'live' AND THERE IS A ROW IN THE DATA_STORE TABLE FOR THIS CARS REGISTRATION NUMBER.
```

There is a registration number field in each of the tables.

Thanks, still getting my head around joins.

Comment: looking up some information about join and left join will be very helpful for you. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp have a read!

Answer (score 2):

You want to do a simple join :

```
select *
from cars
join data_store on cars.registration_number = data_store.registration_number
```

change registration_number with whatever is the link with cars in data_store.

This will return only cars containing a row in data_store.

Comment: Perfect, I'll look into why this works and what happens. Thanks.

Comment: I think the join should be a left join since some information might be missing in the data_store table.

Comment: @A.D no, the OP want only cars that are in data_store.